# Creating a string with items separated by commas from an array results in undefined variable

Tags: php, email

I have an array with email addresses. I need to send a PHP mail to multiple email addresses at once, so I need to have my $to variable like this:

```
$to = 'email@email.com, onemoreemail@email.com, anotheremail@email.com';
```

I use this code to achieve this:

```
$prefix = '';
foreach($result AS $recipient_row) {
    $to .= $prefix . '"' . $recipient_row['email'] . '"';
    $prefix = ', ';
}
```

This results in an `undefined variable: to on line 225`... Line 225 is the line with `$to .= $prefix . '"' . $recipient_row['email'] . '"';`.

The email is being sent to multiple people, so the code does work, but it just produces this error. Why does that happen and how do I stop this error from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `$to` if you want to use `.=`, like this:

```
$prefix = '';
$to = '';
foreach($result AS $recipient_row) {
    $to .= $prefix . '"' . $recipient_row['email'] . '"';
    $prefix = ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
$to = implode(", ", $recipient_row);  // output: email@email.com, onemoreemail@email.com, anotheremail@email.com
```

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) join array elements with a string.

Comment: Do I have to add this to my already existing code? Or should I replace the $to variable with your code?

Comment: No, instead of `foreach` loop you can use `implode` to get multiple email addresses in a string. You don't have to use `foreach` loop.